# Getting tag with specific name in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML file and I have parse it into XDocument.
I need to get all tags with name `<Entity>`, but there is a one problem.

Tag `<Entity>` contains two more Entity tags as his children. (among with many others tag as well).

When I do this:

```
var entity= xmlDoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Entity");
```

I get them all of course.

Is there a way to tell: Get me all Entity tags, but not Entity tag that is child of an Entity tag?

Structure looks like this:

```
<Entity> --> I need to get this one
   <SomeTags>Value</SomeTags>
   <First>
     <Entity>Value</Entity> --> Skip this one
   </First>
   <Entity>Value<Entity> --> Skip this one as well
</Entity>
```

Comment: I would hardly disrecommend using the same tag for two different things if it can be avoided. It will also solve your problem really easy and clean

Comment: You mean any tag having `Value` as value to be skipped?

Comment: @Aimnox I know that, but I have just got the file and words: Solve my problem, and you know how it goes :)

Comment: @HariPrasad No, no There is one Entity tag, and he has Entity tags (totally different that he is as his descendants. I want to skip his descendants and get only him. :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
private String path= @"C:\Temp\xml.xml"; //YOur XML path
public string getValue(string Name)
{
    try
    {
        doc = XDocument.Load(path);
        var dada = (from c in doc.Descendants(Name)
                    where c.Parent.Name!=Name
                    select c).First();
        return dada.Value;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        global::System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There was a problem with the XML");
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got: Enumeration yielded no results :( @Aimnox

Comment: Where? if you take out the where line does it do the same? I just added that line to a method that I use and works so maybe is the added line or maybe something with your XML/path

Answer (score 2):

`Descendants` gets all child elements recursively.  Assuming the elements you want are all at the same depth, you need to find their parent element and query using `Elements` instead - this will only get the immediate children.

```
doc.Descendants("parent")
    .Elements("Entity");
```

If that doesn't work for your structure, you could also literally query as you've suggested - find all those `Entity` elements that don't have any parent `Entity` elements:

```
doc.Descendants("Entity")
    .Where(x => !x.Ancestors("Entity").Any());
```

Comment: I think in the second example you'd need `Ancestors` instead of `Descendants`, since nemo wants `all Entity tags, but not Entity tag that is child of an Entity`. Your example would return all `Entity` elements that don't have children of type `Entity` at all.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yeah I think so as well, example is not returning me anything.

Comment: I got 'Empty = "Enumeration yielded no results"' for both examples. :( @CharlesMager

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer sorry, yes.  Oops, I fixed.

Comment: @nemo_87 for the first query, you need to replace 'parent' with something that matches your XML.  I assume you've only given us a snippet (else your query is just `doc.Root`!)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @CharlesMager's second example, this should be the correct syntax:

```
doc.Descendants("Entity").Where(x => !x.Ancestors("Entity").Any());
```

btw: one of your Entities isn't closed

[Example on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ooYBGf)

Comment: I have: Enumeration yielded no results for this one as well :( @ManfredRadwimmer

Comment: @nemo_87 Works for me, see dotNetFiddle